# How to update all my text _id field from "abc" to "xxx#abc" in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection where the `_id` is a Text field. I need to update this field by adding a prefix to it like **xxx#**, so if a field value was "**abc**" it's must be now "**xxx#abc**"

How can I do that with MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `_id` field in MongoDB's document is **immutable**, You can't perform this operation using `.update()`'s. Since you need to update for all the documents, try to re-write the entire collection using aggregation's [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) stage :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$addFields : {_id : {$concat : ['xxx#','$_id']}}}, {$out : 'collection'}])
```

**Note :** As `$out` will actually replace existing collection (Or creates new one if a collection doesn't exists with given name), test this query very well i.e; test this aggregation query without `$out` stage & if everything looks good then apply `$out`. In other way you can write to a new collection & rename collection names once you think everything is fine. Additionally if you're using MongoDB version >= `4.2` you can take advantage of [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html).